# Disable an entire dropdown when a value is selected from another dropdown

Tags: javascript, dropdown

```
<form class="creation">
<select name="select01" class="select01">
     <option value="01">01</option>
     <option value="02">02</option>
     <option value="03">03</option>
</select>

<select name="select02" class="select02" >
     <option value="aa">aa</option>
     <option value="bb">bb</option>
     <option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Both dropdowns need to be active at first, when i choose one of them, the other becomes disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form select").on('change',function(){
  $("select").not(this).attr("disabled","true")
})
```

Try jquery not

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mec1nd9y/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.disabled`.

**Test Case:** *Select 3 in first select to disable second select*

```js
function validate() {
  var el = document.getElementsByName("select01")[0];
  document.getElementsByName("select02")[0].disabled = parseInt(el.value) > 2;
}

// Bind events
function registerEvents(){
  document.getElementsByName("select01")[0].onchange = validate;
}

registerEvents();
```

```html
<select name="select01" class="select01">
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
</select>

<select name="select02" class="select02">
  <option value="aa">aa
    <disabled/option>
      <option value="bb">bb</option>
      <option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I cannot change html, because I am doing the changes in wordpress

Comment: when i choose one of the selections the other one is still active

Answer (score 0):

```
var el1=document.getElementsByName('select01')[0];
var el2=document.getElementsByName('select02')[0];
el1.onchange = function() {el2.disabled=true;};
el2.onchange = function() {el1.disabled=true;};
```

see demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/01wy66mu/1/)

Comment: i need to do it for wordpress admin page, so i cannot change html. Thank you

Comment: @MariaLaan we can do it in JavaScript also. are you usimg JQuery?

Comment: I am not, I need to add the function to custom.js file